# Jquery form not submitting, or no evidence it's submitting

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to submit an Ajax form using JQuery and just can't spot the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function()
                {

                    $('#photoimg').live('change', function()
                    {
                        $("#emailpreviewloader").html('');
                        $("#emailpreviewloader").html('<img width="180" src="/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');

                        $('#myImageForm').ajaxForm(function() {
                            alert("Thank you for your comment!");
                        });

                        alert("about to submit");
                        $('form#myImageForm').submit();
                        alert("submitted");
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Both alerts fire: "About to submit" and "Submitted", but the Thank you for your comment never fires.

Any idea what is wrong?

EDIT :

The form code:

```
<form id="myImageForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/ajaximage.php">
                            <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
                        </form>
```

Comment: dont use live its deprecated

Comment: What is the structure of your html at page load ? I would say you shouldn't use `.live()` in your case, but I need more info on the structure of your page.

Comment: Do you see the ajax request fire (e.g. : in Firebug, do you see a request beeing sent) ?

Comment: Also, is the request being processed. Check chrome inspector for xhr requests and see if the request goes through

Comment: Does the spinner show?  Do `#photoimg` and `#myImageForm` exist (you'd be surprised)?

Comment: the spinner is good... Actually interesting turn of events... Looks like Wordpress is interfering...

Comment: like @LeGEC said, check out console errors and network traffic

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function()
                {
                    $('#myImageForm').ajaxForm({
                       beforeSend : function(){alert('about to submit')},
                       complete:function(){alert('submited and result recieved')}
                    });
                    $('#photoimg').change( function()
                    {
                        $("#emailpreviewloader").html('');
                        $("#emailpreviewloader").html('<img width="180" src="/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');

                        $('form#myImageForm').submit();
                        alert("submitted");
                    });
                });
```

Try this code and see do you get a about to submit OR a submited and result recieved alert

if you are not getting a about to submit alert then probably the element you are calling .ajaxForm is incorrect.
if you are getting both the alerts then the most probable case is that the server is returning an error

Comment: submitted , alert fires... about to submit does not, submitted and result recieved doesn't fire....

Comment: please make sure that you do have a form with id myImageForm

Comment: extra comment : `.live()` has no use here. I edited the code in your answer.

Comment: @LeGEC - yeah i just copied his code and made some changes to just show what im trying to say

Answer (score 0):

i think you'd better specify the callback you need in ajaxForm via options.

e.g.

```
$('#myImageForm').ajaxForm({
  success: function () { ... }
});
```

also, note that submit() would be an asynchronous function, so alert("submitted"); will be called regardless of whether submit was a success or a failure.

Answer (score 0):

try without jquery form plugin and see what's happened:

```
$(document).ready(function()
                {
/*
                  $('#myImageForm').ajaxForm({
                       beforeSend : function(){alert('about to submit')},
                       complete:function(){alert('submited and result recieved')}
                    });
*/

                    $('#photoimg').change( function()
                    {
                        $("#emailpreviewloader").html('');
                        $("#emailpreviewloader").html('<img width="180" src="/loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');

                        $.post("ajaximage.php",{ photoimg:$(this).val()} ,function(data)
                        {
                            alert(data);
                        })
                       .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                           alert(xhr.responseText);});
                    });
                  });
```

then in your php file :

```
$photoimg=$_POST['photoimg'];
if($photoimg){
    echo "ok";
}
```

you must have an alert saying "ok".
can you also post ajaximage.php and tell us wich version of jquery you're using?